# Adding multiple rows in html table dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Adding a single row in a table (html) and deleting it, using JavaScript, is simple. But, is it possible to add multiple rows, like 2 or more, by calling the *addrow* function only once? The added rows will have different elements, like first row will be having a textfield, the other a textarea and like that...

*Is there any other alternative in html to do that?*

Comment: do you have any code you could show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself by writing code similar to this **:**

adding three rows,first with a textfield,second having a textarea and the third having a button

```
function addRow(tableId)
 {
  var addrow=1;
  var table=document.getElementById(tableId);
  var rowCount=table.rows.length;
  for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
   {
    if(addrow==1)
    {
      var newRow=table.insertRow(rowCount);
      var cell0=newRow1.insertCell(0);
      var element0=document.createElement("input");
      element0.type="text";
      cell0.appendChild(element0);
    }
    if(addrow==2)
    {
      var newRow2=table.insertRow(rowCount);
      var cell0=newRow1.insertCell(0);
      var element0=document.createElement("textarea");
      cell0.appendChild(element0);
    }
    if(addrow==3)
    {
      var newRow3=table.insertRow(rowCount);
      var cell0=newRow1.insertCell(0);
      var element0=document.createElement("input");
      element0.type="button";
      cell0.appendChild(element0);
    }
addrow++;
   }
 }
```

Each time the ***for*** loop runs, a new html element is added in the table and hence I got three rows added dynamically each having a *different* element **.**

Comment: @WooCaSh I don't think so...
But if it is, maybe i'm not able to figure it out and it may be possible that I could have made a mistake writing the code here.In that case your help is required.
Otherwise, the code similar to this one I actually used is working really fine!!!

Comment: You have declaration `var addrow=1;`, but never change param addrow, so in `for statement` this `addrow` always equal **1**. So first `if` will be only executed.

Comment: @WooCaSh I incremented the value of **addrow** by the **addrow++** statement before the end of the **for** loop, after all the **if** conditions. So, the **addrow** parameter is incremented everytime as **for** loop completes one cycle.

Comment: Sorry to earlier for me ;P Wasn't see. My bad. One more time sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your methods as follows:

```
addRow(var rowCount)
{
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
    {
        // Your current implementation to add a row
    }
}
```

Similarly, `deleteRow(var rowCount)` can be defined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function gen_textbox(tr, id, name, type, value){
 td = document.createElement("td");
 tr.appendChild(td);
 var input = document.createElement("input");
 input.setAttribute("id", id);
 input.setAttribute("name", name);
 
 if(type == "text"){
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
 }
 else if (type == "hidden") {
  input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
 }
 else{
  input.setAttribute("type", "pass");
 }
 
 input.setAttribute("value", value);
 td.appendChild(input); 
}

function gen_hiddenbox(node, id, name, value){
 
 var input = document.createElement("input");
 input.setAttribute("id", id);
 input.setAttribute("name", name);
 input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
 input.setAttribute("value", value);
 node.appendChild(input); 
}

function gen_label(tr, id, text){
 td = document.createElement("td");
 tr.appendChild(td);
 var input = document.createElement("label");
 input.setAttribute("id", id);
 var rtext = document.createTextNode(text); 
 input.appendChild(rtext);
 td.appendChild(input); 
}

function gen_label(tr, id, text, td_class){
 td = document.createElement("td");
 td.setAttribute("class", td_class);
 tr.appendChild(td);
 var input = document.createElement("label");
 input.setAttribute("id", id);
 var rtext = document.createTextNode(text); 
 input.appendChild(rtext);
 td.appendChild(input); 
}

function getKeyValueFromJSON(jsonObj, valueNames) {
 
 var value, text = "", temp="";
 obj= '{ "ValueText": [';
 
 for(var i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++) {
  
    text = "";
    for(var j=0; j<valueNames.length; j++) {
     temp="jsonObj[i]."+valueNames[j];
     
     text = text+eval(temp)+" <b>|</b> ";
    }
    value = jsonObj[i].id;
    if(i<jsonObj.length-1)
     obj = obj+'{ "value": "'+value+'", "text": "'+text+'" },';
  else
     obj = obj+'{ "value": "'+value+'", "text": "'+text+'" }';
 }
 
 obj=obj+"]}";
 
 return obj;
}

function gen_select(tr, DrdId, Drdname, multiple, Drdsize, Drdnode, jsonObj) {
 td = document.createElement("td");
 tr.appendChild(td);
 var select = document.createElement("select");
 select.setAttribute("id", DrdId);
 select.setAttribute("name", Drdname);
 
 if(multiple == true){
  select.setAttribute("multiple", "multiple");
 }
 
 select.setAttribute("size", Drdsize);
 var option;
 option = document.createElement("option");
 option.setAttribute("value", "Select "+Drdnode);
 option.innerHTML = "Select "+Drdnode;   
 select.appendChild(option);
 
 for(var i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++){
 
  option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", jsonObj[i].value);
  option.innerHTML = jsonObj[i].value+" : "+jsonObj[i].text; 
  select.appendChild(option);
 }
  
 td.appendChild(select); 
}

function gen_button(tr, id, value, onclk_fun) {
 td = document.createElement("td");
 tr.appendChild(td);
 var button = document.createElement("input");
 button.setAttribute("type", "button");
 button.setAttribute("id", id);
 button.setAttribute("value", value);
 button.setAttribute("onclick", onclk_fun);
 td.appendChild(button);  
}

function gen_button(tr, id, value, onclk_fun, Class) {
 td = document.createElement("td");
 tr.appendChild(td);
 var button = document.createElement("input");
 button.setAttribute("type", "button");
 button.setAttribute("id", id);
 button.setAttribute("value", value);
 button.setAttribute("onclick", onclk_fun);
 button.setAttribute("class", Class);
 td.appendChild(button);  
}

function clearSelected(sel_id) {
    var elements = document.getElementById(sel_id).options;

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].selected = false;
    }
  }
```

First create Generic Function to Add dynamically button, textbox and etc

```js
function create_hiddenBox() {
  
    /*
      This is only for Spring form
      In jsp and spring suppose <form:select path="evp_veh_id.veh_id" size="1" >
      
      var sel_veh = document.getElementById("evp_veh_id.veh_id");
   var veh_name = sel_veh.options[sel_veh.selectedIndex].text;
    */
  
    var node = document.getElementById("evp_footer");
 
 gen_hiddenbox(node, "evp_veh_name", "evp_veh_name", veh_name);
}
```

This is called for call generic dynamically way to make html component using JavaScript